# How to create colspan in createdRow function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to coslpan a certain row with createdRow function? I want to `"colspan="2"` in row with out data "TOTAL". Thank you

```
"createdRow" : function (row, data, dataIndex){
        if ((data["INFO"] === "TOTAL" || data["NO"] === "999")){
            $(row).css({
                "background-color": "#F4D35E",
            });
         };
     },
```

Comment: `$(<selector>).attr("colspan","2");` selector -> the required <td>

Comment: Thanks, for your solution. it's work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(<selector>).attr("colspan","2");
```

***selector*** -> the required `<td>`